# Foreign key constraint does not apply

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I have defined a foreign key. To check it, i insert wrong values to the table that has the foreign key. No error were printed and the values were added succefully. I do not know if i am running some old version of sqlite3 or something like that, i am completely new to this area.

> create table ref(value1 int ,value2,primary key(value1));
>
> create table for(value1 int,value3 int,primary key(value3),foreign key(value1)references ref(value1));
>
> insert into for values (1,1);

This was added succefully.

Comment: Have you enabled Foreign Keys (`PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`)? as per [2. Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are disabled by default as it is explained here: [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).
To enable them execute first:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cDF1Gin3WgB1weNnSkpo2w/1).